# all Sylow subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

Can you give some references to find all Sylow subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$? I know that upper triangular matrices with diagonal's 1 is a Sylow $p$-subgroup where $q=p^n$. But how about the other cases? Thanks!

Comment: If you understand what an irreducible representation is, and how the Sylow subgroups of the symmetric group look like, you can work it out yourself quite easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, for example, A. J. Weir's original paper "*Sylow $p$-subgroups of the general linear group over finite fields of characteristic $p$*" ([link here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1955-006-04/S0002-9939-1955-0072143-9/S0002-9939-1955-0072143-9.pdf)).

**P.S.:** There are some obsolete notation in that article, for example, $A \circ B$ (so called "complete product"), it's just the *wreath product* of $A$ and $B$ ($A \wr B$).