# Sylow $p$-subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018405/all-sylow-subgroups-of-gl-n-mathbbf-q).  However, the answer there isn't particularly helpful.

Consider $G = GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$ where $q = p^{r}$ where $p$ is prime.  Show that the upper unipotent matrices (say $P$) are a p-Sylow subgroup of $G$.

Furthermore, find conditions so that every element of $P$ has order dividing $p$.

Attempt at a solution -

I recognize that this is true.  However, is there an easy way to determine that it is?  I know that the cardinality of $P$ is $q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ and that the cardinality of $G$ is $(q^{n} - 1)(q^{n} - q) ... (q^{n} - q^{n-1})$ but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to factor the above equation.

For the second part, you can write any upper nilpotent matrix $A$ as $I + B$ where $B$ is an upper triangular matrix with $0's$ along the diagonal.  It seems as though by the binomial theorem that $p \geq n$ and $r \geq p - n$ guarantees this.  However, is this the exact characterization of when this property is true?

Edit - this is homework by the way.

Comment: For the first part, you just need to extract the highest power of $q$ form the factored expression. i.e $q^n-q=q(q^{n-1}-1)$, $q^n-q^2=q^2(q^{n-2}-1)$, etc.

Comment: For the first part: $|G| = (q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots(q^n-q^{n-1}) = q^{0+1+\cdots+(n-1)}(q^n-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdots(q-1)$. Here, the exponent of the power of $q$ on the left is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and all the other factors in brackets are relatively prime to $q$ and thus also to $p$.